# Copy reference to avoid NPE if close happens after null check?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp

This is the source code of commons-dbcp2, why can it avoid NPE?

```
public int getNumActive() {
    // Copy reference to avoid NPE if close happens after null check
    GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = connectionPool;
    if (pool != null) {
        return pool.getNumActive();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it copies the reference to a local variable that cannot be modified by external activities.  Note that it copies BEFORE the null check, checks the COPY, not the original, and only references the COPY after the check.  Java GC assures that the referenced object will not be deleted so long as there is SOME reference to it, global or local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the variable `connectionPool` is copied into a new variable `pool`. This pattern of copying references and using the new ref is used when there is chances of multithreading* and the original variable (`connectionPool`) being overwritten/cleared by a different thread.

In this case, if there are two threads, one calling `close` method and other calling `getNumActive` method, then it is possible that first close method clears the connectionPool variable then getNumActive method attempts to run.

If that case happens then even though the original variable clears, its copy (`pool`) survives. So `pool.getNumActive();` never causes an NPE

*In very sloppy terms